# Python, accessing widget items from outside of a class

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have an auto generated code which generates a GUI that has various widgets in it. One of the widget is a ScrolledListBox. A part of the code is shown below:

```
class New_Toplevel_1:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        self.Scrolledlistbox4.configure(background="white")
        self.Scrolledlistbox4.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Scrolledlistbox4.configure(highlightcolor="#d9d9d9")
        self.Scrolledlistbox4.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Scrolledlistbox4.configure(width=10)
```

I want to access the Scrolledlistbox4 from outside this class. So for example, I would like to write to write a function that updates the ScrolledListBox whenever I call it. I am relatively new to python and would like to know how can I accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first create a `Scrolledlistbox4` object as an attribute:

```
self.scrolled_listbox = Scrolledlistbox4(...)
```

then you can do all configures in outermost scope like:

```
a = New_Toplevel_1()

a.scrolled_listbox.configure(background='white')
...
```

---

In below example `"Outside Button"` changes the `text` option of a class' button from the outside:

```
import tkinter as tk

class FrameWithButton(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.btn = tk.Button(root, text="Button")
        self.btn.pack()

root = tk.Tk()

an_instance = FrameWithButton(root)
an_instance.pack()

def update_button():
    global an_instance
    an_instance.btn['text'] = "Button Text Updated!"


tk.Button(root, text="Outside Button", command=update_button).pack()

root.mainloop()
```